# ImportError: No module named apps error in Django Oscar - while including an app in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I received this error when I tried to customize Oscar and add a app called promotions under INSTALLED_APPS

```
(oscar)Macs-MacBook-Air:cyshop Mac$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Mac/virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Mac/virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/Users/Mac/virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Mac/virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/Mac/virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named apps
```

I am not sure if it is not able to pick the apps folder under which I have added promotions.

settings.py looks like this :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks'
]

from oscar import get_core_apps

INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(
['apps.promotions'])
```

My file structure is: 
|cyshop

```
|_init_.py

|db.sqlite3

|manage.py

|settings.py

|apps 

     |_init_.py

     |promotions

          |_init_.py

          |models.py

|urls.py

|wsgi.py
```

Please do help me out. Not sure why the ImportError takes place when I add an attribute into get_core_apps()

Answer (score 0):

You must Agragar your module (apps) to INSTALLED_APPS.Es say

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'compressor',
'widget_tweaks',
"apps",
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your app has a **init**.py ( it could be a blank file)

That was my issue. I deleted that file by accident and then I got the same error as you.

Making a new file **init**.py inside the app's folder fixed it right up

EDIT: I see that you have the file. This is just a notice for any others who stumbled across this Question via search.